# Pyomo + Cplex - OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, cplex, pyomo

I am trying to get Cplex working with pyomo.
I have followed Cplex installation instructions has explained here: [Downloading and setting up CPLEX for Pyomo](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4366/downloading-and-setting-up-cplex-for-pyomo)

However when calling Cplex via pyomo I get the following:

```
File "...\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 607, in solve
    result = self._postsolve()
  File "...\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\CPLEX.py", line 906, in _postsolve
    results = ILMLicensedSystemCallSolver._postsolve(self)
  File "...\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py", line 251, in _postsolve
    OUTPUT=open(self._log_file,"w")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '"C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmppc5loeps.cplex.log"'
```

I have verified that `C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community201\cplex\bin\x64_win64` is in the Path variable

Comment: You could find the useful answers for your question by searching on community. For example [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5468/how-to-collect-solutions-within-cplex-and-retrieve-them-from-pyomo) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079490/how-to-connect-cplex-and-pyomo) one. Do you try that?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The first link is not relevant. As for the second I have verified that Cplex is in the path variable

Comment: A bit unlikely on Windows but it could be a permissions issue, are you certain that your program has write access to that directory? You can try running in administrator mode just to make sure.

Comment: Running VSCode as an admin produces the same error